# Could not load file or assembly 'xxx.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found

Tags: c#

I am attempting to load 64bit dll into a 64 bit platform. I keep on getting the error below. I googled it for and tryed a lot of suggestion. I cleaned the solution rebuilt. Still have the same problem. Any suggestions. 
Ps: It is for a C# WFP i am writing.

```
"Could not load file or assembly 'xxx.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found"
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

This can occur if the assembly you load has dependencies on *other* assemblies which aren't available when the process tries to use the type.

You can check the `InnerException` property of the exception, which often provides more details.  If that doesn't work, the best way to diagnose is to use the [Fusion Log Viewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which is Microsoft's tool for diagnosing assembly load issues in detail.

Comment: I am try to use the Fusion Log Viewer. The problem is i have  Visual studio 2010 express and Visual studio 2012 express installed. I can only find the FUSLOVW in V8.0A and not in the 7.0A for the Visual studio 2010. The one i found also contains no log files or data of any kind. Are they the same? If not where else can i find the one for visual studio 2010